# Hiding a UILabel from a UITableViewCell doesn't resize the contentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, autoresize

I'm trying to create a dynamic `UITableView` where a `cell` can expand/collapse as the user selects the `cell`.

```
- (void)setUpCell:(DynamicTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.label.text = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.secondLabel.text = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:self.dataSource.count - indexPath.row - 1];
    if ([self.isVisible[indexPath.row] isEqual:@NO]) {
        cell.secondLabel.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.secondLabel.hidden = NO;
    }
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataSource.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DynamicTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self setUpCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DynamicTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.isVisible[indexPath.row] isEqual: @YES]) {
        self.isVisible[indexPath.row] = @NO;
        cell.secondLabel.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        self.isVisible[indexPath.row] = @YES;
        cell.secondLabel.hidden = NO;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static DynamicTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    });

    [self setUpCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:cell];
}

- (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(DynamicTableViewCell *)sizingCell {
    [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    return size.height;
}
```

I forked [this](https://github.com/tjosten/iOS-UITableViewCell-with-dynamic-height) project and have the test code [here](https://github.com/pwiebe/iOS-UITableViewCell-with-dynamic-height).

Once the cell has been sized it does not change when selecting the cell, only hides/shows the content of the cell.  I've tried replacing the explicit size calculation with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.  Also tried reloading the cell.  Seems once the cell size has been calculated, it does not change.

Any suggestions as to what to try would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS development a view **never** collapses if you set the `hidden` property to `true`.

Instead you should use autolayout. Assuming your view has two labels vertically stacked on top of each other, pin the first label to the cells contentView's top, give it a height constraint, pin the second label's top to the first labels bottom, pin the second labels bottom to the cell's contentView bottom. Set the height of the second label, and save this constraint in a variable, lets called it *secondLabelHeightConstraint*, now you can collapse and expand the cell by setting the value of *secondLabelHeightConstraint* to 0 or what ever value you would like.

Comment: Thanks!  This ended up working, with a few additional changes to ensure the variable height of the UILabel.

Comment: Nice Philip, glad to help! I guess maybe you have some Android experience? Because in Android you can set view.setVisibility(View.GONE); and then that view will "collapse". it is a bit trickier in iOS. Autolayout is the way to go :)

Comment: Saved me some time. I did figure it out eventually before bumping here, but this kind of explained it to me. Thanks.